# How to create a video page where after starting the video everything else blacks out and video centers on the browser?

Tags: html, flash

I have seen that on some websites after starting some video on the page everything else blacks out and the video starts playing. How can this be done? Is it possible only with some specific video types like flash?

Answer (score 0):

Create a big div thats the size of the browser window, give it a z-index of 100 or so, and then give the video a z-index that is one higher. Make the background of it black, and maybe with some opacity.

.someDiv{
    background: black;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    .video{
      z-index: 101;
    }

And then use JS to make the div show up when you click play. Also have a separate "Dim Lights" button.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [Lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29).

It's commonly used to show images, but can be used to put focus on anything on a page. Given that; no, it's not only compatible with flash, as you can apply the effect to any element.

Aside from writing a custom one just for video elements, such as `flash` and `<video>`, you could probably just modify an [existing one](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its a very useful tool.